# Using AngularJS to post form data to a ViewModel that is defined within ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I would like to collect some data using AngularJS and post it back to my ASP.NET WebAPI controller.

I have defined my business object like this (which just aims to record overall annual petrol consumption along with consumption every month):

```
public class PetrolViewModel
{
    public double petrol_annual { get; set; }
    public int petrol_measure { get; set; }

    public List<Month> months { get; set; }

}

public class Month
{
    public double jan { get; set; }
    public double feb { get; set; }
}
```

In my Angular code I have:

```
var app = angular.module('petrol', []);

app.controller('PetrolController', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.petrol = {};

$scope.petrol.months = {};

$scope.sendForm = function() {
    $http({
        method: 'Post',
        url: 'api/values',
        data: $scope.petrol
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(headers);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(headers);
    });
};

});
```

When I submit the form data and leave the WebApi controller to receive an anonymous object it seems to work and I get my form data:

[image: Debug information when passing in an object type]

But, if I change this and try to pass in the ViewModel I defined earlier I get a null object being passed in:

[image: Null object when trying to pass in as ViewModel]

I want to take full advantage of the ASP.NET features to automatically map the matching names and deliver me a populated Object that I can then handle in my code. I don't want to have to map the anonymous object to the ViewModel.

So, the programming question is: How do I make sure my AngularJS object can be matched to a ViewModel?

In tutorials I've been watching this seems to "just work" for everyone else so they tend not to cover it in much detail.

Here is the JSON that is being sent up, according to Fiddler:

```
{"months":{"jan":"10","feb":"10","mar":"10","apr":"10","may":"10","jun":"10","jul":"10","aug":"10","sep":"5","oct":"5","nov":"20","dec":"10"},"petrol_annual":"120","petrol_measure":"1"}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the JSON you're sending up?

Comment: Sure. So Fiddler tells me it's sending up this: {"months":{"jan":"10","feb":"10","mar":"10","apr":"10","may":"10","jun":"10","jul":"10","aug":"10","sep":"5","oct":"5","nov":"20","dec":"10"},"petrol_annual":"120","petrol_measure":"1"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why `petrol_annual` or `petrol_measure` aren't model binding correctly, but the `List<Month>` needs to be `Month` instead:

```
public class PetrolViewModel
{
    public double petrol_annual { get; set; }
    public int petrol_measure { get; set; }

    public Month months { get; set; }
}
```

This is because `months` in the JSON is an object, not an array. It should match up with the `Month` class on the server. The `Month` class should also include entries for all months, but you may have just ommitted those for brevity in your OP.

Comment: For some mysterious reason this fixes it, though I have no idea why. I was assuming that because petrol_annual and petrol_measure were not binding the problem was elsewhere. It didn't occur to me that incorrectly using List<Month> was somehow causing the whole thing to fail. I was getting nothing indicative of this in debugging, but could have been looking in the wrong place. Anyway, I'm very grateful for your answer as I would have been scratching my head over that all night.

Answer (score -1):

Below works. Perfectly fine.
Code:

```
public class CatergoriesViewModel
{

    public string OrderSelected { get; set; }
    public string CatergoryName { get; set; }
}

var data = { catergoryName: "TestCat", orderSelected: "true" };
    $http.post("Category", data)
 .then(function (response) {
     $scope.test = response.data;
 }, function (error) {
     $scope.test = error;
 });
```

Comment: Ehem. Yes. As is typical with many developers today, the code is misspelled terribly, but runs "Perfectly fine". (CatergoriesViewModel, plus CatergoryName, and catergoryName) #letthisbealesson to us. We can take the extra 0.5 minute to proof what we type.

Comment: I second the above comment, this seems like a weak attempt to garner points on SO